# Require Nokogiri? No such file to load

Tags: ruby, netbeans, rubygems, jruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get started with using Nokogiri. I ran the command

```
gem install nokogiri
```

as an administrator in Windows 7 (64-Bit). The console said "successfully installed" and "1 gem installed".

When I type in

```
gem list --local OR gem q --local
```

I see Nokogiri on the list of "Local Gems".

However, when I try to use it via the require statement (in NetBeans), I get an error that there is "no such file to load".

What am I doing wrong? I'm not a Ruby professional. This is also the first gem I've installed. Please dumb it down for me.

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: Netbeans comes with built in ruby - jRuby. Wich version is used in project's properties - yours or built-in?

Comment: Try RubyInstaller http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Comment: Yes Viacheslav, you are correct! I was using JRuby by accident. I have corrected the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans comes with built-in jRuby.

You can specify or check wich version of ruby currently used in your project in project's properties (higlighted section).

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Thanks, Viacheslav!

Answer (score 20):

With Ruby 1.8, you have to `require 'rubygems'` before requiring any libraries installed as gems. With Ruby 1.9, that is not necessary anymore.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have tried using your suggestion, and it does not work. However, I do have Ruby 1.9 anyway.

Comment: Oh, I have figured out the problem! NetBeans was using JRuby 1.5 instead of 1.9. Thank you for pointing out versions, or I would not have checked this!

Answer (score 10):

I realize this post is pretty old, but others may stumble here with the same problem, as I did.  Novices like me may not realize that

```
require 'rubygems'
```

must precede

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

At least, based on another URL post that gave me the idea, the addition of that line solved the problem for me with nokogiri.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this one for a while, having upgraded to ruby 2.0.

The fix was to install nokigiri using apt-get

```
apt-get install ruby-nokogiri
```

As a side note dependencies can be seen using

```
$ gem dependency nokogiri

Gem nokogiri-1.6.1
  hoe (~> 3.7, development)
  hoe-bundler (>= 1.1, development)
  hoe-debugging (>= 1.0.3, development)
  hoe-gemspec (>= 1.0, development)
  hoe-git (>= 1.4, development)
  mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
  minitest (~> 2.2.2, development)
  racc (>= 1.4.6, development)
  rake (>= 0.9, development)
  rake-compiler (~> 0.8.0, development)
  rdoc (~> 4.0, development)
  rexical (>= 1.0.5, development)
```