# require 'nokogiri' issue with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby

I have made a Ruby project (not rails project) in Netbeans, and in main.rb file i have been requiring nokogiri but i am getting the following error.

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /home/nadeem/rails_project/RubyApplication1/lib/main.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I have installed nokogiri 1.5.0 and using ruby 1.9.2

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Using [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage your gem dependencies is probably a good idea because you can check if things are set up properly using `bundle check` if you've declared and successfully installed them.

The bundler setup routine can import many gems in the proper order, accounting for dependencies. Otherwise you will need to have at least this:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'nokogiri'
require 'nokogiri'
```

Make sure that the gems are installed with the same version of Ruby you're trying to run. It's easy to get mixed up when you're using rvm and have inadvertently added the gems to a different version.

Comment: can we have Gemfile in simple Ruby project?? i am not reffering to the rails project.

Comment: Bundler works with any Ruby project. You just need to add [a few lines](http://gembundler.com/bundler_setup.html) to your main file and it'll work.

Comment: sorry i forget to let you know that i have been using rails 3.2.2

Comment: It works with any Ruby project, but Rails uses it by default.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this solution hope this will be helpful, Check your net bean's project properties and try to update path from there.

[Require Nokogiri? No such file to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496018/require-nokogiri-no-such-file-to-load)

Comment: Thanks @mfq, i have tried the same solution. I went to project properties and my there was correct ruby version associated with this project. Thanks any how. Any more idea???

Comment: Try to check the path where Ruby is install, I thinks that could be the cause of problem, you could be missing that